# Remove comma from input type number on javascript

Tags: javascript, php

now im doing PHP project combine with JQuery. i make a form page that have `<input type="number">`

From this input, i make a rules for limit 2 decimal behind. here is the code

```
<input 
type = "number"
onkeypress = "return isNumeric(event)"
oninput = "maxLengthCheck(this)"
name ="cost">
```

JS

```
function maxLengthCheck(object) {
    if (object.value.length > object.maxLength)
      object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.maxLength)

    var prev = object.getAttribute("data-prev");
    prev = (prev != '') ? prev : '';
    if (Math.round(object.value*100)/100!=object.value)
    object.value=prev;
    object.setAttribute("data-prev",object.value)
}

function isNumeric (evt) {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode (key);
    var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
    if ( !regex.test(key) ) {
        theEvent.returnValue = false;
        if(theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

the code can work correctly. but however when insert more then 2 decimal behind the (.)dot. the (.)dot will change into (,)comma.

ex. "19.459". on input will display "19,45". this is wrong

the correct is
ex. input "19.878" i want to display "19.87"

i make a sample on this site https://repl.it/@ferdinandgush/add-2-decimal-behind. just click "run" buttom on the top and you able to test it

how do i still able to keep the (.)dot evendo i type another number behind (.)dot ?

Comment: the dot didn't change into comma in firefox and chromium, maybe your browser's outdated?

Comment: 19.459 comes out as 19.459. There is no change. also you cannot put a comma into a number type input. Kindly reproduce error !

Comment: @Kristian i tried it on my chrome and still display (,) comma

Answer (score 0):

You are probably in a country that normally uses a comma as the decimal separator and browsers use that for `<input type=number>` display.

Some browsers, such as Firefox, use the [`lang` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang) to determine the language to use, when it's set on the input or any of its parent elements, so you could do that.

However other browsers such as Chrome do not respect that `lang` attribute. If you need this to work in all browsers, then your only choice is, as far as I can say, not to use `<input type=number>`.